Oracle ORA-01031: insufficient privileges on SYSTEM user
In oracle, when logged in as user: 'SYSTEM', I can't seem to view results of:
Select * from sys.USER$

However, of if I log in as 'sys as sysdba' I see results.
Any idea what's going on

They are different users with different permissions. Why do you want to query that internal table directly - what do you need from it that isn't in dba_users or some other view system can see?

Most dictionary tables (not views) require explicit object grants and are not included in the typical select any dictionary role that SYSTEM and most DBA-like accounts have. But unless you have a rather advanced need here (and that only if you're a DBA), you shouldn't be querying these underlying tables directly. This particular table contains a hash of the user's password. While you cannot reverse engineer this back to the password, you can compare it to other users or on other databases to make predictions about password reuse that serve a hacking purpose. So it should be off-limits.
